# How would I run jquery code once a value is selected from a dropdown list?

Tags: jquery

The HTML involved is similar to this:

[image: This is a picture of the html.]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/a88XG.png

I cannot change the html, it is auto generated. I need to perform an event once a specific "option" is picked from the dropdown list, however at the moment I can't reference it, as nothing in the html seems to change.

For example, once changed to option 2, call an alert.

Thanks guys.

Comment: Why don't you post the actual markup, and not a picture of it?

Comment: What is it with you and spaces in your ids? Whitespace isn't allowed in the id or name attribute.  You're asking for problems if you don't correct this.

Comment: I can't change the IDs!! Its oracle crm code!

Comment: @idb - if it can't even get the HTML ids right why would you trust it to do anything else right?

Comment: I don't, and it often doesn't, but I have no option unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is listen for the `change` event with jQuery which is raised when the seletion is changed.  After which you can query to see if the particular one you're interested in is selected

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#EditForm.SR').change( function() {
    if ($('#EditForm.SR option:selected').val() === 'Option2') {
       // Option 2 is selected
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: @JaredFarrish yes. One of the overloads allows you to specify simply the callback

Comment: This still doesn't work for me :(. Guess it's a limitation of the system.

Comment: That was why I suggested instead of said it was; I figured I may have not known of an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Your elements' IDs have spaces in them which is not allowed:

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

But you could try getting the `<select>` by class name:

```
$('select.inputControl').bind('change', function() {
  // Do what you need to here.
});
```